# Getting "Connection refused" error while trying to connect to nodeport in kubernetes minikube

Tags: curl, kubernetes, minikube, connection-refused

deployment.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
 name: deploymnt
 labels:
 name: deploymnt
spec:
 replicas: 2
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   hello: hi
 template:
  metadata:
   name: deppod
   labels:
    hello: hi
  spec:
     containers:
       -  name: c2
          image: httpd
          ports:
           - containerPort: 80
```

Service.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: demoservice
spec:
 ports:
  - port: 80
    nodePort: 32201
 selector:
   name: deploymnt
 type: NodePort

after applying
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
demoservice   NodePort    10.105.148.95   <none>        80:32201/TCP   5h4m
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        10d
```

after applying both yamls and then curl:-

1. Curl From the local host

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15ISK:~/kubeprac$ curl 10.105.148.95:32201
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.105.148.95 port 32201: Connection timed out
```

2 Then I used the minikube's ip from local host

```
minikube service list
|-------------|-------------|--------------|---------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |    NAME     | TARGET PORT  |            URL            |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|---------------------------|
| default     | demoservice |           80 | http://192.168.49.2:32201 |
| default     | kubernetes  | No node port |
| kube-system | kube-dns    | No node port |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|---------------------------|

ubuntu@ubuntu-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15ISK:~/kubeprac$ curl http://192.168.49.2:32201
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 32201: Connection refused
```

3. Then I went inside the minikube and the do the same

```
docker@minikube:~$  curl http://192.168.49.2:32201
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 32201: Connection refused
```

Please help !!!
I am not sure what is getting wrong here. Even the selectors and label seems to be fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your host machine allows kubernetes node ports range are allowed.
You can check this by running the command below

```
sudo ufw status numbered | grep tcp
```

And you show see a line like this

```
 30000:32767/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

If you don't it, run this command to add the ports range

```
sudo ufw allow 30000:32767/tcp
```

Comment: it didn't worked :(   I ran the command ```sudo ufw allow 30000:32767/tcp
``` ,but still I am not able see anything ``` 30000:32767/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere ``` like this. Also getting the same connection refused error

Comment: Make sure all kubernetes ports are allowed as show in the documentation. But it should work. 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem nodePorts would never work for me
I was running minikube on wsl2 backend (docker driver) for windows 10
switching to hyperv solved this problem.

to switch i ran
$minikube delete
followed by
$minikube start --driver=hyperv

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).